# Windows Phone 8 Multiple Pushpin Cluster

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, bing-maps, markerclusterer, pushpin

i'm adding a list of pushpins to bing maps with clustering. After that i want to access which one information but i'm not being abble to define the correct binding for that. I tried two ways to define Pushpin Template (as MapItemsControl or in PhoneApplicationPage.Resources). I´ve already tried define the DataContext when i add a new pushpin to the list but it also didn't work.

Whitout the clustering it works fine with both solutions.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you using a cluster library?

Comment: i follow the example on this page: [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18194.windows-phone-8-development-maps-and-clusters.aspx).
But i have a different template, because i want to show the pushpin content when i tap it. the cluster works, but when i add the pushpin to the list, i try to pass an object (class) as data context but didnt work.
thanks a lot